# How to run a python script from root directory in blocks?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

my project structure looks like this -

```
<project_name>

--Makefile
--notebook
--src
  -- __init__.py
  -- utils
     -- __init__.py
     -- general_imports.py
  -- modelling
     -- train.py
```

I have specific recipe for different operations like `make - train, predict` etc, and they look like this -

```
train: src/modelling/train.py 
    python -m src.modelling.train
```

My **train.py** looks like this -

```
from ..utils.general_imports import *
from ..utils.dataset import *

def main():
    train,test = csv_to_dataframe() # Method returns dataframe from csv

    print("Taking a glance at the dataframe")
    print(df.head())

    print("Shape of the dataframe")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Now this works perfectly fine except one thing - it runs everything in script in one go. While this is expected, it makes hard to do any analysis as I need to run `make train` which runs everything from start. One way I got it working is by creating a Jupyter notebook in the `notebook` folder and later copy pasting the code into `train.py`. This comes with a cost of changing relative imports and some other changes.

Is there any better way to incorporate ipynb notebooks, or maybe execute my `train.py` in cell wise manner when I do `make train`. My approach doesn't look neat and it makes me to repeat the work in `ipynb` notebook as well as `py`file.

Comment: The requirements seem rather irreconcileable; `make` is geared towards batch processing and automation, whereas you want interactive behavior. The best I can suggest is to split `train.py` into a batch wrapper which loads code from your notebook somehow, and have the smaller snippets as executable cells in the notebook

Comment: @tripleee I get it. Would you suggest to have a notebook for train along with train.py to visualize interactively and then merging the functions in train.py once I decided what works and what doesn't (train.py as final incorportated file to use for automation).  I have other utility functions which I can import in train notebook as well, just need couple of adjustments and change in relative imports. Thanks for the help.